# Android NDK:undefined reference to ' '

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, linker-errors, ld

I am trying to build a library file of g729 codec.i have source of this codec and trying to build using Android NDK.
Almost all object files are built but at last i am getting this error.
But i am stuck with this error. can anyone explain the meaning of this error and what should i do to solve this?

```
./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/g729_jni/g729/cod_ld8a.o: In function `Coder_ld8a':
/root/g729/jni/g729/cod_ld8a.c:267: undefined reference to `Pitch_ol_fast'
/root/g729/jni/g729/cod_ld8a.c:325: undefined reference to `Pitch_fr3_fast'
/root/g729/jni/g729/cod_ld8a.c:328: undefined reference to `Enc_lag3'
/root/g729/jni/g729/cod_ld8a.c:344: undefined reference to `G_pitch'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks

**Edit**
I have solved this error but **is it feasible**?
I have added this line in Android.mk

```
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
```

Comment: "undefined reference to" is a linker error. You probably forgot to pass a library to link in on the command line.

Comment: okay can you tell me how to pass a library in command line using NDK?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know NDK at all. Probably it's the same as usual, `-l<name>` where `<name>` is the name of the library. Which library you are missing, no idea. But if NDK is/contains a kind of an integrated build system or IDE, you'll not invoke the compiler via the command line, instead you'd list the library in some project file.

Comment: ahh ,thanks for your explanation but here, even i can't understand which library file i am missing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are compiling the sources and you want to link the resulting library you can use one of the following variables in your Android.mk file

> LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES:
>       The list of static libraries modules (built with BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
>       that should be linked to this module. This only makes sense in
>       shared library modules.
>
> LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:
>       The list of shared libraries *modules* this module depends on at runtime.
>       This is necessary at link time and to embed the corresponding information
>       in the generated file.

For more details have a look at the android NDK documentation that you can find in the ndk folder.

Otherwise if you have to link a prebuilt library there is a section in the Android NDK documentation that tells you how to achieve the result. An on-line version of these documents is also [here(PREBUILTS)](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/PREBUILTS.html).

**UPDATE 09/01/2017**

Documentation about Prebuilt libraries can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html)